# Select nth child in jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web, selector

select nth child like this I want to select seconds child .

```
$(this).prev().children[1].removeClass("necry").addClass("necry_er");
```

And this HTML

```
<div class="reg_label">
    <div class="def">Family</div>
    <div class="necry">Necessary Field</div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I expect this result:

```
<div class="necry_er">Necessary Field</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use the :even selector? http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Comment: this time I need second another time i'll need 5th...

Comment: ok and the second or next time the fifth always has the same class? if so, take the parent and look for that class.

Comment: What are you expecting `.children[1]` to give you? That's not a valid thing. Maybe you want `.eq(1)`?

Comment: I expact this div <div class="necry"> Necessary Field </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to reduce a set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
$(this).prev().children().eq(1).removeClass("necry").addClass("necry_er");
```

There's also a [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

```
$('#elementID:nth-child(2)').doSomething();
```

To just swap the two classes you can do:

```
$('.necry').toggleClass('necry necry_er');
```

How exactly to go about finding the element you want is a little hard to tell, as there is no explanation as to what `this` is or what context it is in ?

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this?

```
var nec = $(this).parent().find(".necry");
nec.removeClass("necry");
nec.addClass("necry_er");
```